# Fortran equivalent of Numpy functions

Tags: numpy, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to translate something from Python to Fortran because of speed limitations. (So I can then use f2py on it.)

The problem is that the code contains many NumPy functions that don't exist in Fortran 90. So my questions is: is there a Fortran library that implements at least some of the NumPy functionality in Fortran?

The functions that I have to use in the code are generally simple, so I could translate them by hand. However, I'm trying not to re-invent the wheel here, specially because I don't have that much experience in Fortran and I might not know some important caveats.

Anyway, here's a list of some of the functions that I need.

```
np.mean (with the axis parameter)
np.std  (with the axis parameter)
np.roll (again with the axis parameter)
np.mgrid
np.max  (again with axis parameter)
```

Anything is helpful at this point. I'm not counting on finding substitutes for all of them, but it would be very good if some of them, at least, already existed.

Comment: Are you applying these functions to whole `numpy` arrays?  Or using them iteratively?  If your `numpy` code is already making good use of functions like this, translation to Fortran or C (via Cython) might not gain all that much.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm using them to whole NumPy arrays, but the whole thing is inside two large loops that I can't get rid of. So I think there's no way around it (except maybe using Cython, but I don't have to time to learn cython right now).

Comment: Unlike Python loops are not a bad thing. Python loops are slow, Fortran loops are fast. The special functions, if they exist, will be shorter to use, but not really faster than a well optimized (e.g., vectorized) loop.

Comment: cshift() may be a friend of np.roll... (and possibly spread() + implied do-loop is a friend of np.mgrid??) But I guess to get speedup, it is probably necessary to rearrange the computation somewhat and merge some calculations into a single loop (though not sure at all...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the intrinsic list of procedures from gfortran is useful as a first reference here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html#Intrinsic-Procedures

1. `np.mean` (with the axis parameter)
   See sum. It has an axis parameter. In combination with size it can output the mean:

   ```
   result = sum(data, dim=axis)/size(data, dim=axis)
   ```

   Here, result has one less dimension than data.
2. `np.std`  (with the axis parameter)
3. `np.roll` (again with the axis parameter)
4. `np.mgrid`
5. `np.max`  (again with axis parameter)
   See maxval, it has a `dim` argument.

I am not aware of a Fortran equivalent to NumPy. The standard-based array abilities of Fortran are such that a "base" library has not emerged. There are several initiatives though:

1. https://github.com/astrofrog/fortranlib "Collection of personal scientific routines in Fortran"
2. http://fortranwiki.org/ "The Fortran Wiki is an open venue for discussing all aspects of the Fortran programming language and scientific computing."
3. http://flibs.sourceforge.net/ "FLIBS - A collection of Fortran modules"
4. http://www.fortran90.org/ General resource for modern Fortran. Contains a "Python Fortran Rosetta Stone"

Comment: Not an intrinsic, but if you do implement a mean function using the sum+size combo suggested here, you can also define std with a one-liner using e.g. the mathematical identity Var[x]=E[x^2]-E[x]^2: `std = sqrt(mean(data**2,dim=axis))-mean(data,dim=axis)**2)`

Comment: There is also the Fortran interface to the GNU Scientific Library: https://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/